# How to make sure a wide table using hvfloat and hv0box is on the correct page

Tags: tables, width, books, hvfloat

I have several big tables which I am splitting up over multiple pages for a book width-wise using hvfloat and hvObox.

In order for this to work the table needs to be placed on pages that are next to eachother in the book (e.g. page 1-2, but not on page 2-3). Since latex places it whereever it feels like this often goes wrong.

How do I make sure that the table is placed on the correct pages?